# Как отобразить файлы из .gitignore в общем списке по проекту?

Tags: git, atom, gitignore

С недавних пор Atom убрал из списка файлов проекта (любого имеющегося у меня) все файлы, которые прописаны в файле .gitignore.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вернуть все эти файлы обратно в структуру проекта?

Comment: "убрал" = "стер" или "убрал" = "скрыл в списке файлов"?

Comment: @Эникейщик скрыл. Эти файлы есть в директории проекта. Если удалить их из `.gitignore`, то они появляются в списке в Atom'e. Это не круто и не понимаю как такое произошло и как вернуть как было.

Comment: Значит где-то в настройках должна быть соответствующая галочка. У меня атома нет, а то бы подсказал где она.

Comment: @Эникейщик я туда первым делом полез. Не увидел.

Comment: Ээ, гугл по запросу «atom gitignore show files» выдаёт решение в первых же ссылках. Например https://michaelsoolee.com/atom-ignored-files/

Answer (score 0):

Открой config Atoma, найди там "hideVcsIgnoredFiles", задай false.